# SVM classifier for uniform distribution

Tags: machine-learning

We have a dataset where in each attribute class, the values are distributed uniformly something similar to the following image where safety is one attribute of the dataset:
[image]

If all other attributes have the same situation then how does SVM classifier perform on this dataset? Which kernel should be used with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "each attribute class"? Is it about the distribution of the target class or the distribution of the attribute (feature)? Anyway the performance of SVM depends on the full dataset, I don't see how the univariate distribution of a feature indicates anything.

Comment: @Erwan It is about the distribution of the attribute (feature) not the target class.

Comment: the distribution of a feature on its own is not really relevant, the performance depends on whether the features as a whole contain enough information to predict the class. However if all the features have a high correlation with each other then it's possible that they are too similar to to help the model.